# Ionic framework, build app on ionic serve auto forward to google search hotlinking

Tags: ionic-framework, build, local, hotlinking, serve

When i build app in browser with commandline "ionic serve", my app forward to google search hotlinking. However when i build app with android "apk" sometime it's failed

Answer (score 0):

try to build a blank project. If the error still appears, you need to check your installation and dependencies. Check this guide of how can you install all necessary dependencies for development. 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/installation.html

Comment: Just adding an observation that that link points to the Ionic 1.x documentation. If you are using Ionic 2+, the link would be [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/installation/)